# How many wireless xbox 360 controllers can be active in the same room?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

Soon I am going to host a Halo 3 LAN party with 16 people in my living room.
At most two people will share a screen, so we are talking about at least 8 consoles.

When 16 people are using wireless controllers in the same room will any of them cause interference with each other?

Comment: I have a feeling you may be doing live research on this one...

Comment: It *should* work. Gaming tournaments use plenty of controllers too, just in a bigger room.

Comment: I will update this question with my findings when the party is over.

Answer (score 1):

After a very fun nostalgic Halo 3 System Link party I can say that it worked in my situation. So I conclude that 16 controllers should be fine.